# Google Cloud Bug - Issue deploying node js app to google cloud instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've downloaded the latest hello world node js app from google cloud.

I can run the app locally using npm start and then by visiting localhost:8080 and I see the app running.

I've also created a project and have a project id.
I've also enabled billing like the tutorial suggests.

This is the tutorial I am following: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

**I then go to deploy the app with this command in the google cloud sdk:**

gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote

**I then can this message in my console and its not very helpful:**

[image]

**This is the tutorial part I'm following:**

[image]

**Then this is the screen I get when I visit the website on the google cloud instance (It should say hello world):**

[image]

Comment: Are you still stuck on this?

Comment: Yeh. I got two friends to try do it aswel and they couldn't. Googles docs need updating

Comment: I moved to Amazon ec2 now and worked first time